# Creating new cumulative list of lists from existing list

Tags: python, list, loops

Using Python, I am trying to build a cumulative list of lists where each element in the list grows by the number of values of the previous element in the list. The code example below should make it clearer.

```
my_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
list_new = []
final_list = []

for i in my_list:
    list_new += i
    final_list.append(list_new)
```

I am trying to get a result of

```
[
  [1,2,3]
, [1,2,3,4,5,6]
, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
]
```

But I am getting

```
[
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
]
```

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
>>> my_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> list(itertools.accumulate(my_list))
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to make a copy of the list new and add that final list, rather than adding the `list_new` itself.

The reason for this, is a list is a reference type so appending to it will be modifying any other places this list is referenced, so instead, you're creating a new list.

```
final_list.append(list_new[:])
```

[Example](https://ideone.com/oquoXf)

Answer (score 0):

In one line it would look like this:

```
result = [[element for sub in my_list[:i] for element in sub] for i, _ in enumerate(my_list, 1)]
result
#[[1, 2, 3]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the final_list contains three references to the same list_new.
Instead, you want to clone the list every time you push it to final_list.
You can do this by

```
final_list.append(list(list_new))
```

Altogether:

```
my_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
list_new = []
final_list = []
for i in my_list:
  list_new += i
  final_list.append(list(list_new))
```

Answer (score 0):

`+=` mutates the single list `list_new` in place, and you repeatedly add a reference to that same list to `final_list`. You need to add a *new* list to `final_list`.

```
my_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
list_new = []
final_list = []

for i in my_list:
    tmp = list_new + i
    final_list.append(tmp)
    list_new = tmp
```

Or, instead of creating a new list then rebinding the name `list_new` to it, keep updating `list_new` in-place but add a *copy* to `final_list`.

```
my_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
list_new = []
final_list = []

for i in my_list:
    list_new += i
    final_list.append(list_new[:])
```

Or, use `itertools.accumulate` and stop worrying about the accumulator yourself.

```
from operator import add
from itertools import accumulate

my_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
final_list = list(accumulate(my_list, add))
```

You can omit the explicit `add` argument, as `accumulate` will use that by default.

```
final_list = list(accumulate(my_list))
```

Comment: `add` operator is not needed (it's the default).

Comment: Ah, right. I was confusing that with `sum`, where `sum(my_list)` would fail but `sum(my_list, [])` would work (as `sum` needs some help to know which `+` to use).